# Moving from one monitor to another on a Dual monitor system

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, multiple-monitors, mouse

I am using 13.04 on a laptop with an additional screen connected so that when I'm designing websites, the 2nd monitor is used as a preview page to reduce the need to shuffle through windows to find the one I need.

## The Problem

The problem is that I can easily move from the main screen to the 2nd screen (on the right) without any problems, however, getting back to the working window, Screen 1 I hit a barrier at the screen edge an I have to take a run up and force my way over what seems like a barrier. 
[image]

## The Question

Can anyone tell me where the setting is for reducing or eliminating this 'step' between screens.

Thank you in advance.

## Edit

This was happening when I had the Unity Launcher displayed on both windows, but stayed there when I selected the option to keep the Launcher on the main screen (Screen 1) only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may need to know in the future, I uninstalled the proprietary driver for my Nvidia card and installed the Open Source drivers, rebooted, then reinstalled the proprietary  drivers again, it has fixed it :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it could be the "Sticky Edges" feature. You can disable it in System Settings>Display, at the bottom of the options list.

Comment: I've been using Ubuntu for a month and I keep forgetting these little things, there are so many of them! Thank you so much for the quick response +1 and a tick from me, to hide my embarrassment!

Comment: Sorry had to un-tick as the problem has returned. Sticky edges are disabled :( any other ideas?